# Render knockout templates 'inline'

Tags: javascript, html, templates, knockout.js, whitespace

The tile may be a bit confusing but let me show you what I want.

Consider the following knockout templates:

```
<script type="text/html" id="my-template">
    <span data-bind="text:text"></span>
</script>

<div data-bind="foreach: nodes">
    <!-- ko template: {name: 'my-template'}--><!-- /ko-->
</div>
```

This will result in something like:

```
<div>
    <span>Text </span>
    <span class="bold">bold</span>
    <span>.</span>
</div>
```

To avoid the space the HTML is given to spans on e new line, I want to rander the spans on the same line, like this:

```
<div>
    <span>Text </span><span class="bold">bold</span><span>.</span>
</div>
```

I am aware of the font-size:0 workaround, but that is not the fix I'm looking for because I can not oversee the issues for projects which are already using the current rendering templates.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this issue before where the resulting empty text nodes created were causing bigger issues than just whitespace on screen.

It's caused by the fact that *anything* within the relevant sections (both the template and the `<div>` in your case) is part of that section, and will be repeated alongside the actual content you're interested in.  That includes all the whitespace before/after the `<span>` in your `<script>` template, and that before/after the inline comment knockout directives.

One quick fix is to ensure your template doesn't have any extraneous whitespace in it outside of your `<span>`:

```html
<script type="text/html" id="my-template"><span data-bind="text:text"></span></script>
```

In your case you also need to remove the whitespace from inside your repeating `<div>` contents too:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: nodes"><!-- ko template: {name: 'my-template'}--><!-- /ko--></div>
```

For example:

```js
var vm = {
  nodes: ko.observableArray()
}

vm.nodes.push({ text: 'one'   });
vm.nodes.push({ text: 'two'   });
vm.nodes.push({ text: 'three' });

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Without whitespace</h2>
<script type="text/html" id="my-template"><span data-bind="text:text"></span></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: nodes"><!-- ko template: {name: 'my-template'}--><!-- /ko--></div>
<h2>With whitespace</h2>
<script type="text/html" id="my-template-ws">
  <span data-bind="text:text"></span>
</script>
<div data-bind="foreach: nodes">
  <!-- ko template: {name: 'my-template-ws'}--><!-- /ko-->
</div>
```